# How to group "Only in" lines in diff at the beginning of the output

Tags: linux, diff, recursive

I did:

```
diff -r directory1/ directory2/
```

Some files are different, and some files were only in one tree or the other, creating several `Only in ...` lines.

How do I group these lines at the beginning of the file? I am 99.9% sure that neither directory contains any line that begins with `Only in`. I was considering something like:

```
diff -r directory1/ directory2/ | grep -v `^Only in`
```

But that removes them, rather than groups them. And `sort` doesn't do what I want either, because I want to keep the actual comparisons in their order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach might be to redirect the `diff` output to a file and then use `grep` to segregate the two parts:

```
diff -r directory1/ directory2/ > temp
{ grep '^Only in' temp; grep -v '^Only in' temp; } > diff.output
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to do this in one line? Not crucial, just curious.

Comment: @durron597 Not any way that I can think of!